# Ambiguous Implicit Resolution Error With Doobie

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-cats, doobie

I have this function that inserts a One To Many relationship representation between 3 tables:

```
def insertRelations(cs: TableA): Fragment = {
    sql"""INSERT INTO my_schema.table_a (
            id,
            name,
            dataType,
            longName,
            externalNumber,
          ) VALUES (
            ${cs.name},
            ${cs.dataType},
            ${cs.longName},
            ${cs.externalNumber},
          )"""
      .update.withUniqueGeneratedKeys[Int]("id")
      .flatMap { tableAId =>
        val bSeqs: Seq[TableB] = cs.tableBSeqs
        bSeqs.traverse_ { elem =>
          sql"""insert into table_b (
                  tableAId,
                  externalName,
                  readValue,
                  isFormatted,
                  meanValue,
                  createdAt,
                  updatedAt
                ) VALUES (
                  ${elem.tableAId},
                  ${elem.externalName},
                  ${elem.readValue},
                  ${elem.isFormatted},
                  ${elem.meanValue},
                )"""
            .update.withUniqueGeneratedKeys[Long]("id")
            .flatMap { tableCId =>
              val cSeqs: Seq[TableC] = cs.tableCSeqs
              cSeqs.traverse_ { elem =>
                sql"""insert into table_c (...., ...., ....) values ($...., $...., ....)"""
                  .update.run
              }
            }
        }
      }
  }
```

I have the following imports in scope:

```
import doobie.Fragment
import doobie.implicits._
import cats.implicits._
```

When I tried to compile this, it ran into the following error:

```
ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both lazy value WeakAsyncBlobIO in trait Instances of type doobie.WeakAsync[doobie.free.BlobIO]
[error]  and lazy value WeakAsyncCallableStatementIO in trait Instances of type doobie.WeakAsync[doobie.free.CallableStatementIO]
[error]  match expected type cats.Applicative[G]
[error]               bseqs.traverse_ { elem =>
```

Both my traverse throws up this ambiguous implicit error. Is there any implicit scope that I'm missing?

Comment: On the contrary: you have two implicit values in scope that match and the compiler doesn't which one it should choose. I don't know Doobie to be able to tell you which one to keep and what import to use though. You can try by removing the `import doobie.implicits._` and then import progressively what's raised as needed by the compilation (IDE should help for that).

Comment: That kind of helped. It is getting scary for me to trust on these implicits.

Comment: _Yeah.. that's strength and weakness of the implicit mechanism! Or to be fair, that the strength of the mechanism but some libraries abuse it in. (Personal opinion of course)_

Comment: But I agree that importing should be scoped and the wildcard should be done only if I depend on more than 3 or 4 types of a specific package.

Comment: Also try to just use `import cats.syntax.all._` instead of `cats.implicits._`

Comment: I think issue might be also that you letting infer two higher-kinded values at once when you run `.traverse_`. Error message suggest that compiler tries to infer some `F[_]: Applicative` based on available implicits and there are 2 of them matching. (Also you call traverse on `Seq` which isn't helping, AFAIK `Traverse` was defined for specific implementations like `List` or `Vector` but for `Seq` it was absent, at least it used to be true).

Comment: Actually, for Scala 2.13.12 I managed to compile your snipped merely by changing the return type from `Fragment` to `ConnectionIO` - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/IBCF95etRjKUvQoBuPEDfQ . For Scala 3.3.1 I needed to manually provide `Pos`, probably macro failed to generate position for Scastie snippet - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0G0hvK0ATR2s1LEhQbmEpg . Are you using 1.0.0-RCn version of Doobie, some other Scala version or have other imports?